# Join linq to another Linq query

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have a this Simple Query:

```
var query=(from p in customer.salary
          select new{
                     p.name,
                     p.family
          }).toArray();
```

and i have a another query:

```
var query2=(from p in customer.price
            select new{
                   p.Sumprice
            }).toArray();
```

How can i join query with query2:i want join quert resualt with query2 resualt.

Or how can i access the two table field or return two table field for example query return 
two table fields name and Sumprice.

Thanks.

Comment: there's absolutely no relation between the two entities ?

Comment: No my entity in dbml file dont have relation

Comment: and you have as many rows in salary than in price ? Or you have only one item in one of your entity ? The problem is : which sumprice should be related with a name ? Could you show an example, with some sample datas, and the desired output ?

Comment: in my Salary table or entity i have a name field and name data=akbar and in my price table i have a price field and price=20000 how can i write query to show me akbar 20000

Comment: Show us all the fields of the `salary` table and all the fields in the `price` table. Then, tell us which field(s) in the `price` table are related (have the same data) to the field(s) in the `salary` table.

Comment: Thanks for all,solve its